# Why do java programs start with a class definition?

Tags: java, class

It is said that a java program itself is a class, but I just don't get the logic behind this.

The java program itself starts of by the definition of a class (after importing the packages...etc) and the main method itself is defined inside a class.

Why is it this way?

Why does a main method have to be included within a class rather than outside as a separate method/function like in the languages such as c, c++...etc.

For example a simple hello world program in java:-

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world!"+"Hello again");
    }
}
```

Why is it necessary that a program should start with a class and the main method included within it?

Comment: So that JVM starts from there ?

Comment: Java is an object oriented language, it does not support procedural programming.

Comment: keeping in mind that Java is a *class based object oriented* language: why not? C++ is a good example what happens without this restriction...

Comment: "Why is it this way" Because that's the way [the language was defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1). It could have been different, but it's not. It was just a design decision made once upon a time.

Comment: Actually, @csirmazbendeguz, Java does support procedural programming -- method calls, the control structures, recursion, subprograms returning values, it supports all that. It just does it within classes, as Andy Turner has said.

Comment: @SureshAtta Well yes, it starts from the main method which is the starting point of a program. But why would it be included inside a class ? That was my question.

Comment: @AndyTurner , well you're wrong. There is a lot of reasons behind this method of design. It's given in detail, on the java specifications.

Comment: @steve Where you want to write then?

Comment: @steve what exactly are you saying I'm wrong about? And why accept an answer which says exactly the same thing, just in more detail?

Comment: @AndyTurner because it has more accurate answers to accept it ?

Comment: @SureshAtta Outside a class, like for example in c++.

Comment: @GhostCat It was pretty accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Java language specification says so! See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4) for example. Or more precisely:

> The Java Virtual Machine starts up by loading a specified class and then invoking the method main in this specified class.

(to be found right in the beginning of chapter 12, [Execution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html)).

Sometimes there isn't a "big" reason behind things.The fathers of the java language probably had a look around what other languages did at that time when they started Java. They decided to go for this approach - and there was never a hard, pressing reason to come back and change that.

Beyond that: you have to understand that the JVM doesn't care about Java source code. It only cares about the Java bytecode specification - and **complete** classes coming in as compiled .class files.

In other words: there is simply no other "unit" that could wrap around single methods/functions but classes.

Comment: Chapter 12 and chapter 5 of the specifications explained the process in detail, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The JVM doesn't understand the concept methods outside of a class. Fundamentally any method called by the JVM will have to be in a class. The main method is static as at the start of a java application nothing will have been initialised, so making it static allows the JVM to call it as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

The Java Virtual Machine (JVM) has to start the application somewhere. As Java does not have a concept of “things outside of a class” the method that is called by the JVM has to be in a class. And because it is static, no instance of that class is created yet.